# ElasticSearch: Adding a normalizer for case-insensitive search on keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a large ES index with dynamically created "keyword" fields. I need to enable case-insensitive search on these. I understand analyzer is not available for keyword fields, and normalizer is to be used for it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html

Is there a way to dynamically add normalizers to fields/mappings? I am able to add an analyzer to existing text fields by closing the index, adding the analyzer and reopening the index. This does not seem to work on existing indexes while adding normalizers. Is there a way to do this other than creating another index to re-index all the data?

Here are my steps:
Create a test index with the lowercase normalizer:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/ganesh_index/ -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "useLowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "ganesh_type":{
        "properties":{
           "title":{
              "normalizer":"useLowercase",
              "type":"keyword"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

Now, I can insert and query as desired:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/ganesh_index/ganesh_type/1 -d '{"title":"ThisFox.StatusCode1"}'
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/ganesh_index/ganesh_type/2 -d '{"title":"ThisFox.StatusCode2"}'

curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/ganesh_index/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"regexp":{"title": "this.*code1"}}}'
{
  "took" : 24,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "ganesh_index",
        "_type" : "ganesh_type",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "ThisFox.StatusCode1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, if my index already exists like so:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/ganesh_index -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 2,
      "number_of_replicas": 2
    }
  }
}'
```

and I insert records, I am unable to add the normalizer later.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/ganesh_index/?pretty -d '
> {
>   "settings": {
>     "analysis": {
>       "normalizer": {
>         "useLowercase": {
>           "type": "custom",
>           "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "mappings":{
>      "ganesh_type":{
>         "properties":{
>            "title":{
>               "normalizer":"useLowercase",
>               "type":"keyword"
>            }
>         }
>      }
>   }
> }'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_already_exists_exception",
        "reason" : "index [ganesh_index/mg5TckzaR5KZDE-FphTeDg] already exists",
        "index_uuid" : "mg5TckzaR5KZDE-FphTeDg",
        "index" : "ganesh_index"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_already_exists_exception",
    "reason" : "index [ganesh_index/mg5TckzaR5KZDE-FphTeDg] already exists",
    "index_uuid" : "mg5TckzaR5KZDE-FphTeDg",
    "index" : "ganesh_index"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Is there any way to add the normalizer for an existing index (on keyword fields)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will have to either re-index it or create a new mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Elasticsearch doesn't give support for such activity.
Even if you did it will give us a message with this.

```
 {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [category_video_autocomplete_3/FkxOwP_RQMW_L077hYLPJg] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "FkxOwP_RQMW_L077hYLPJg",
        "index": "category_video_autocomplete_3"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason": "index [category_video_autocomplete_3/FkxOwP_RQMW_L077hYLPJg] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "FkxOwP_RQMW_L077hYLPJg",
    "index": "category_video_autocomplete_3"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The message looks quite complicated but a closer look tells

```
resource_already_exists_exception
```

meaning the resource you want to create already exists, so we can not create the same resource, here resource means **index** named category_video_autocomplete_3.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the concept of [Dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html).
We can define a dynamic mapping like below which will apply the normalizer with name "my_normalizer" to all the future keyword fields of type string .
However , we need to define dynamic settings as part of mapping before creating the index , so that You can then use dynamic templates to define custom mappings that can be applied to dynamically added fields based on the matching condition:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "my_normalizer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [],
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```